# Can't run Google Chrome in the terminal of Mininet clients

Tags: networking, command-line, display, google-chrome, xterm

I am using Mininet in Linux as a simulator. When I enter Xterm h1 and enter google-chrome in the terminal of h1 I get these errors.

[image]
<sup>Could not open the default X display.</sup>

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7915).